# Skiasharp how to get coordinates from touch location after scaling and transform

Tags: xamarin, skiasharp

I have an Xamarin project where I am using Skiasharp.  I am relatively new to the drawing utility.  Ive spent a few days trying to figure out this issue with no luck.  After scaling and transforming the canvas, when I touch the skcanvas view on the phone screen and look at the 'location' point in the touch event, its not the same location that the canvas drew something. I need the exact location I drew the rectangle.

Its a lot of code below and granted its not all the code, but its the important parts. I am absolutely baffled why I draw in one (X,Y) location yet when I touch the screen the touch event for the canvas gives me a completely different location than what than the (X,Y) the widget was drawn at.
'''

```
public static void DrawLayout(SKImageInfo info, SKCanvas canvas, SKSvg svg, 
SetupViewModel vm)

var layout = vm.SelectedReticleLayout;
float yRatio;
float xRatio;
float widgetHeight = 75;
float widgetWidth = 170;
float availableWidth = 720;
float availableHeight = 1280;

var currentZoomScale = getScale();
canvas.Translate(info.Width / 2f, info.Height / 2f);
SKRect bounds = svg.ViewBox;

xRatio = (info.Width / bounds.Width) + ((info.Width / bounds.Width) * currentZoomScale);
yRatio = (info.Height / bounds.Height) + ((info.Height / bounds.Height) * 
currentZoomScale);
float ratio = Math.Min(xRatio, yRatio);

canvas.Scale(ratio);
canvas.Translate(-bounds.MidX, -bounds.MidY);
canvas.DrawPicture(svg.Picture, new SKPaint { Color = SKColors.White, Style = 
SKPaintStyle.Fill });

// now set the X,Y and Width and Height of the large Red Rectangle
float imageCenter = canvas.LocalClipBounds.Width / 2;
layout.RedBorderXOffSet = imageCenter - (imageCenter / 2.0f) + 
canvas.LocalClipBounds.Left;
float redBorderYOffSet = (float)(svg.Picture.CullRect.Top + 
Math.Ceiling(.0654450261780105f * svg.Picture.CullRect.Bottom));
layout.RedBorderYOffSet = (float)(canvas.LocalClipBounds.Top + 
Math.Ceiling(.0654450261780105f * canvas.LocalClipBounds.Bottom));
layout.RedBorderWidth = canvas.LocalClipBounds.Width / 2.0f;
layout.RedBorderWidthXOffSet = layout.RedBorderWidth + layout.RedBorderXOffSet;
layout.RedBorderHeight = (float)(canvas.LocalClipBounds.Bottom - 
Math.Ceiling(.0654450261780105f * canvas.LocalClipBounds.Bottom * 2)) - 
canvas.LocalClipBounds.Top;
layout.RedBorderHeightYOffSet = layout.RedBorderYOffSet + layout.RedBorderHeight;

// draw the large red rectangle
canvas.DrawRect(layout.RedBorderXOffSet, layout.RedBorderYOffSet, layout.RedBorderWidth, 
layout.RedBorderHeight, RedBorderPaint);

// clear the tracked widgets, tracked widgets are updated every time we draw the widgets
// base widgets contain the default size and location relative to the scope. base line 
widgets
// will need to be multiplied by the node scale height and width

layout.TrackedWidgets.Clear();

var widget = new widget
{
X = layout.RedBorderXOffSet + 5;
Y = layout.RedBorderYOffSet + layout.TrackedReticleWidgets[0].Height + 15;
Height = layout.RedBorderHeight * (widgetHeight / availableHeight);
Width = layout.RedBorderWdith * (widgetWidth / availableWidth);
}

// define colors for text and border colors for small rectangles (widgets)
public static SKPaint SelectedWidgetColor => new SKPaint { Color = SKColors.LightPink, 
Style = SKPaintStyle.StrokeAndFill, StrokeWidth = 3 };

public static SKPaint EmptyWidgetBorder => new SKPaint { Color = SKColors.DarkGray, 
Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke, StrokeWidth = 3 };

public static SKPaint EmptyWidgetText => new SKPaint { Color = SKColors.Black, TextSize 
= 10, FakeBoldText = false, Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke, Typeface = 
SKTypeface.FromFamilyName("Arial") };

public static SKPaint DefinedWidgetText => new SKPaint { Color = SKColors.DarkRed, 
FakeBoldText = false, Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke };

// create small rectangle (widget) and draw the widget
var widgetRectangle = SKRect.Create(widget.X, widget.Y, widget.Width, widget.Height);
canvas.DrawRect(widgetRectangle, widget.IsSelected ? SelectedWidgetColor : 
EmptyWidgetBorder);

// now lets create the text to draw in the widget
string text = EnumUtility.GetDescription(widget.WidgetDataType);
float textWidth = EmptyWidgetText.MeasureText(text);
EmptyWidgetText.TextSize = widget.Width * GetUnscaledWidgetWith(widget) * 
EmptyWidgetText.TextSize / textWidth;

SKRect textBounds = new SKRect();
EmptyWidgetText.MeasureText(text, ref textBounds);

float xText = widgetRectangle.MidX - textBounds.MidX;
float yText = widgetRectangle.MidY - textBounds.MidY;

canvas.DrawText(text, xText, yText, EmptyWidgetText);
```

'''

Comment: the touch event (you don't show the code so I'm assuming) is using the device coordinate system, while Skia uses it's own coordinate system.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/basics/pixels

Comment: The touch event is the SKTouchEventArgs and you get the X and Y by e.Location.X and e.Location.Y.  Those values are not the same location as the rectangle.  If I remove scaling and transformation...then it is the same location.  Also I have been on that webiste for 3 days...I have yet to find the answer to help with this situation

Comment: oh, I see.  I would assume that applying the same scale and transform to the touch coordinates would then get the same result?  Some pictures that illustrate the issue might help

Comment: I thought so as well.....but it didnt.  For example...a small red box is drawn at (408, 328) with a width of 55 and height of 28,  yet in the touch event, when after I touch the red box, the X is 333 and the Y is 186 which is not anywhere near the coordinates it was drawn at.

Comment: Then you have not correctly adjusted those numbers, to account for translation and scale. First, make sure it works at several different positions, when no translation or scale. Then keep scale 1, translate 100 in x. Does touch x change by 100? -100? Some different amount?

Comment: … You should observe a pattern. Like “translating by 100 increases all x values by 100.” So, you have to do the OPPOSITE, to get back the desired x. Unfortunately, scale complicates this. Get it working first with default scale, various translations.

Comment: I could never get it working. If I do not ResetMatrix() after scaling the image, the touch points are never the same.  I can take the scale values from the TotalMatrix and times that by the touch points but its still wrong.  So I simply reset the matrix after scaling the image and I will have to manually grow and shrink the rectangles.  @toolmakerSteve I am sure I have done something wrong, not pointing out anything I dont know...hints why I posted on here :)

Comment: As I said, DO IT FIRST WITH SCALE OF 1. (Only a translation.) Can you get that to work? Do you understand that if you translate by +100, then you need to SUBTRACT 100 from touch x, to get back the "correct x"?

Comment: After you get that working, test with only scale (no translation). Again, you have to do the OPPOSITE to get from touch back to "correct x". If scale is 2, DIVIDE by 2. After you get that working, only then should you try both translation and scale. You'll have to experiment to find out which "opposite" you should do first. If x-translate=100 and scale=2, I don't know whether the correct formula is `imageX = (touchX/2) - 100;` or `imageX = (touchX - 100) / 2;`.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thank you for the help, the later of the two is the correct answer.  I am not sure how to post an answer on here but for others wondering how to get the drawn location from the touch location after translate and scale, get the values from canval.TotalMatrix.Values and use the transform values in the formula above.  
touchlocation.X - translateXValueFromTotalMatrix / xScale
touchlocation.Y - translateYValueFromTotalMatrix / yScale